# Is it allowed that we use usecase diagram just for 1 actor (user)?

Tags: uml, diagram, software-design, use-case

I use use case diagram that only include 1 actor (user) because my website don't have admin. I have build WebVR who is user can see 360 3D model in their browser. Can I use usecase diagram for it although just only 1 actor/user?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, what makes you think otherwise?

If your system only has one Actor then that is how it is. There is absolutely no reason why you wouldn't be able to use a use case diagram for the analysis of a system like this.